# Classic ASP - Website localization

Tags: dictionary, vbscript, asp-classic

I need to add Languages support to an existing classic asp website

The "best" solution I found is to encapsulate every text in a function,
create a database table where store, for every page, the translations and use a dictionary object to retrieve the right value.

example:

```html
<div>Welcome to xy website</div>
<button class="btn green">Login</button>
```

becomes

```html
<div><%=TL("Welcome to xy website")%></div>
<button class="btn" ><%=TL("Login")%></button>
```

then TL function should be like this

```
Function TL(strInput)
    Dim strTargetLanguage, strPageURL,objDict,strTmp1,strTmp2
    if strInput<>"" then
        ' First check if customer has set language.. else uses browser language
        if request.cookies("culture")="" then 
            strTargetLanguage=lcase(left(request.servervariables("HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"),2))
        else
            strTargetLanguage=lcase(left(request.cookies("culture"),2))
        end if
        ' if User's Language is not supported....
        if instr(strAcceptedLanguages,strTargetLanguage)= 0 then        
            strTargetlanguage="en"
        end if

        strPageURL=Request.ServerVariables("URL")

        Set objDict=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        objDict.Add "strPageUrl",strPageUrl

        'Stored Procedure to load translation in the required language and for the target Page      
        cmd.CommandText="spDictionaryRead"
        cmd.CommandType=4
        cmd.Parameters("@LanguageID")=strTargetLanguage
        cmd.Parameters("@PageUrl")=strPageURL
        set rst=cmd.Execute()

        if not rst.eof then
            while not rst.eof
                objDict.Add rst("txt"),rst(strTargetLanguage) 
                rst.movenext()
            wend
        end if
        rst.close

        if objDict.Exists(strInput)=true then
            TL=objDict.Item(strInput)           
        else        
            ' Custom Function to translate using google
            TL=Translate(strInput,"en",strTargetLanguage)

            TL=Replace(TL,"'","''")
            strInput=replace(strInput,"'","''")
            'Add new Sentence to Dictionary
            cmd.CommandText="spDictionaryWrite"
            cmd.CommandType=4
            cmd.Parameters("@PageUrl")=strPageURL
            cmd.Parameters("@TXT")=strInput
            cmd.Parameters("@TargetLanguage")= strTargetLanguage
            cmd.Parameters("@TargetText")=TL
            cmd.Execute()

            set objDict=nothing
        end if          
    else
        TL=""
    end if
End Function
```

The function is not ready since at present every time it is called it access the DB  and load all the translations of the page and create the Dictionary:
in this situation would be better to avoid the Dictionary and directly Query the DB for the sentence required.

I need "ONLY" to find a wise way to store the dictionary "somewhere" so to avoid to rebuild it
But which to choose? Application, Session, objVariable into the page, ???

googling a little I realize that Application is not a wise solution for many reasons,

Session: I try to keep session very slim: I would never save an object  with some 30-50 Keys if I can avoid.... unless I remove it at the end of the page itself (if it worth)?

Someone suggest to load translations into Application as "plain array" and then build Dictionary every time it is required, but while loading the sentences into the Dictionary I can test if current sentence is target sentence and extract the translation without using Dictionary..
therefore neither this is a wise solution

I read also about

> Lookup Component from Microsoft

but couldn't find any docs

perhaps can use some .NET components, like HashTable?

Since I imagine that translations are a common issue, I expect there has to be a better solution, and that my approach is wrong:

Can pls suggest a better approach or some hints?

Comment: In the past I've used a similar approach with one difference the function doubles as an admin mode which allows the function to double as an admin interface that accepts input from a Textbox. This approach allows the database to be updated but you can also build a local cache file, I've used XML files. It's very flexible because if you are not loading the page in admin mode the function just pulls the data from the cache files.

Comment: Hi, Interesting the TextBox solution: for this website I used different approach since are frequent users: since machine translation is poor I added a modal frame where every user, if does not accept automatic translation, can customize every sentence and have its own Dictionary. But how to use a XML File as cache file? can give me a couple of more hints?
Thanks!

Comment: If I get time today I'll try and leave a more complete answer, but the approach does work and have companies using this out in the wild now for over 15 years.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but take your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A while ago I inherited a project from another developer and to date in Classic ASP I haven't found a more efficient way of handling localisation.

The basic premise is

1. Store key-value pairs in a database, the structure we used is a `keys` table containing the keys and a "section" *(which denotes a particular grouping of keys)*. We then have our `values` table which contains language specific localisations associated to the key by a FK *(1:M)* relationship.

   ```
   ╔══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
   ║     Keys Table                                                   ║
   ╠══════════════╦══════════════╦═════════════════╦══════════════════╣
   ║ id (int, PK) ║ key (string) ║ section (string)║  editpanel (bit) ║
   ╚══════════════╩══════════════╩═════════════════╩══════════════════╝

   ╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
   ║     Values Table                                                    ║
   ╠══════════════╦═════════════════╦═════════════════╦══════════════════╣
   ║ id (int, PK) ║ key_id (int, FK)║ lang (string)   ║  value (string)  ║
   ╚══════════════╩═════════════════╩═════════════════╩══════════════════╝
   ```
2. Build a ASP application to create the XML from the key-value pairs in the database. The application is basically two pages

   1. Iterates through the supported languages and sections *(defined in the `keys` table)* in a nested loop, this is how we decide on logical separation of cache files. Within each iteration we pass the work to a another page via a `WinHttpRequest` object. The page returns an XML structure that is has built by looking in the database and pulling out all the key-value pairs that are related to the specific section being iterated.
   2. As already a mentioned a page specifically built to be called by the `WinHttpRequest` object that after querying the database for the specific section key-value pairs returns them in a bespoke XML structure.
3. Store a file structure something like

   ```
   \packs\ ┐
           ├ \de\
           ├ \es\
           ├ \fr\
           ... etc
   ```

   that includes a sub directory for each language supported in the database. The directories need to be accessible by Web Application Identity *(whether that's a `IUSR` or a pre-configured account)* with at least `Modify` permission to allow the creation and modification of the cached XML files.

   The bespoke XML files look something like this

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <language_pack>
     <strings>
       <string id="391" key="connect" editpanel="0" section="email">
         <![CDATA[Connect]]>
       </string>
       <string id="9" key="uploadimage" editpanel="0" section="common">
         <![CDATA[Upload Photo]]>
       </string>
       <string id="12" key="notes" editpanel="0" section="common">
         <![CDATA[Notes]]>
       </string>
     </strings>
     <error_messages>
       <error id="1" key="pleasebepatient">
         <![CDATA[\nThis action may take a little time!\nPlease be patient.\n]]>
       </error>
     </error_messages>
     <info>
       <langcode>gb</langcode>
       <langname>English</langname>
       <strings>194</strings>
       <time>0</time>
     </info>
   </language_pack>
   ```

   *<sup>XML file truncated to keep things simple, actual files contain a lot more values</sup>*

The main localisation is then powered by an `#include` file that get's added to each page that needs to support localisation *(it just becomes part of the build process when working in localised web applications)*.

The `#include` we call `locale.asp` does something similar to what you describe in the question. It made up of various functions of which the main ones include;

- `init_langpack(langcode, admin, section)` - Handles any initialisation of the XML cache file. The `langcode` is just the string representation of the language you want to load *(collates to the directory names, `de`, `es` etc)*. `admin` determines whether we are in "Admin Mode" or not and behaves slightly differently if we are, setting page headers etc. and `section` is the XML file *(which we separate into sections)* we want to load into an XMLDOM object. It should always be called before attempting to access `ml_string()` as it loads the XML.
- `ml_string(id, showcontrol)` - Used the ASP pages where we want to output a localisation the `id` is a key from the XML / Keys table *(why both?, will explain in a bit)*, while the `showcontrol` Boolean is used to decide when the page is displayed in "Admin Mode" so we can show the localisation in an editable field or not. You might not always want to do this due to how localisations are placed in the page *(allowing you to handle them differently, display a panel underneath etc)*.

Comment: Hmmm.. I see, with section you do not mean "page" right?
therefore you can have more section in same page...
But then, how to understand which section you're translating?
Anyway XML can avoid to use Dictionary with all its limitation:
concerning DB I used only 1 table with fields like key, page, en,de,fr,it......

Anyway thank a lot for you Sunday Time!

Comment: Sorry @joe still contemplating adding more to this answer. Basically the `init_langpack()` procedure should be called whenever you want to load the localisations for a specific section *(which is just a logical grouping of localisations)*. So you can swap and change as you want to, I do tend to load them based on the page though and then have a "common" section that also is loaded into each cache XML as part of the XML generation which allows me to have specific localisations shared across the app that get loaded with any section `init_langpack()` call.

Comment: Yes, I have a "common" section, in fact I select with  
`WHERE Page='xxx.asp' or 'common'` :-)
but OK it is all clear!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Joe We use a similar approach but because we have other "special" sections like `config` for example we use an `IN()` and build up a comma delimited string of the sections that should be included to create the cached XML file and pass them to it.

Answer (score 2):

I use `Application` for caching of some objects in Classic ASP, usually as an array with the values retrieved from the database with `GetRows()`.

`Session` isn't suitable as it is only available to one user, not all users like `Application`.

For your situation where you probably want to cache a LOT of data I have a suggestion.

When you retrieve your values from the database you could create an ASP script with the File System Object which contains the VBScript code to create your dictionary and populate with values. Then you could include this generated ASP page in all of your files.

For example, to build your cache file...

```
<%
datestamp = Year(Now()) & Month(Now()) & Day(Now()) & Hour(Now()) & Minute(Now()) & Second(Now())

set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set tfile=fs.CreateTextFile(Server.MapPath("\cache\language_" & datestamp))
tfile.WriteLine("<%")
tfile.WriteLine("Set objDict=Server.CreateObject(""Scripting.Dictionary"")")

'...your database code here....
        while not rst.eof
            tfile.WriteLine("objDict.Add " & rst("txt") & ",rst(strTargetLanguage)")
            rst.movenext()
        wend
'...etc etc...

tfile.WriteLine("%>")
tfile.close
set tfile=nothing
set fs=nothing

Application("languagecache") = datestamp
%>
```

NB. The datestamp in the filename is there so that there is no issue when the cache is being built.

Then, in your ASP pages you could include the latest cache file using `Server.Execute`...

```
Server.Execute("\cache\language_" & Application("languagecache"))
```

This is all just an example. You should also add code to ensure that if a page is accessed before the first time the cache file is built that it gets content from an include file that is always going to be there. You would also add in some code to check when the last time the cache file was generated and generate a new one after a set time. You might do this is a scheduled task so that some poor user doesn't have to wait while the cache file is built (or just start it asynchronously).

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for answering. 
About Application/Session, since same sentence in English can have different translation in other language according to the context, every time I will load only translation for that specific page. If I save into Application surely will avoid to read from database for most common languages and pages, but if I'm lucky (ie: have a lot of visits from different countries) since I have more than 40 pages, I could find at the end of the day with some 200-400 arrays in the Application each with 20-30  values:  seems me a lot of space used..

Comment: If you are running a dedicated/VPS server and have sufficient memory available then it might not matter if you store a LOT in Application variables. If you are on shared hosting then it will matter. Do you need to store your translations in a database? You could just have translation include files for each language, that you include dynamically based on the user's setting (using `Server.Execute`).

Comment: have a cloud VPS with 4GB RAM, but RAM is never enough...
yes translation need to be on DB because every (registered) user can customize it, therefore every time somebody load a page we need to modify the relative application variable: target is to load only once and not for each sentence to be translated. therefore in this conditions best solution probably is to store it in an array and pass it to the function

Comment: Caching your translations using the file system method I suggested would be quite efficient if you create a cache file for each language, include the appropriate file dynamically, and this would not use a lot of RAM like storing all the languages in Application variables.

Comment: Agreed, application variable storage is a bad idea. Found working with cached structured file far more efficient and flexible.